# Why I am unable to push viewcontroller to the next viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, function, pushviewcontroller

I am working on sockets in objective-c so i wrote a function for getting response of server when my condition comes true i want to push to the next view controller but it is not pushing or presenting plz help
some code is given here

this is my function

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, 
       CFSocketCallBackType type,  
       CFDataRef address, 
       const void *data, 
       void *info)
{
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    char *buffer = (char *)CFDataGetBytePtr((CFDataRef)data);

    if (strstr(buffer, "LCNF|ACPT") == NULL)
    { 
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        [lvc alert];
    }
    else

        [lvc goToWatchList];
}
```

my "goToWatchlist" method is:

```
-(void)goToWatchList
{

    WatchListViewController *wlController = [[WatchListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WatchListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:wlController animated:YES];
    [wlController release];
}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Thanks to 7KV7 for reformatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something very similar before. Are you sure it even reaches your `[lvc goToWatchList];`
 within `receiveData`? Also check that your reading from socket is not blocking the thread!

Also check your xib file - if this cannot be found it won't appear either... (Ups - already been mentioned while I was typing...)

Comment: thanks for answer
my nib file is ok if i call "goToWatchlist" from any other method or IBAction, it works fine but if i call it from my function "receiveData" then it goes to the method and control goes to its own "loadView" after after line of pushViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is happening on the main thread. Also make sure that wlController is not nil after the init message in case the nib cannot be found or there is a problem with it.

You create a new LoginViewController here:

```
LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
```

But I don't see where you are adding that to a view. You push your WatchListViewController onto that, but it can't appear because its parent (the LoginViewController) is not showing up. Yes, the loadview on LoginViewController -(void)loadView will be called because you are adding something to it (the WatchViewController), but since that view isn't being displayed, it doesn't need to load the LoginViewController's view.

Try adding this code to the end of receiveData:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:lvc.view];
```

If that doesn't work, try changing to the goToWatchListFunction to present the modal view controller on the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].

Comment: thanx for reply wlController is not nil infect i am trying to go to watchlistViewCOntroller from LoginViewController but control goes to the loadview of loginViewController after presentModel line

Comment: are you ever actually adding the lvc view to your view hierarchy? In the code above, you are not. Therefore, you are pushing the new modal view onto a view that isn't even being displayed at the moment.

Comment: All of the given code is written in LoginViewController & lvc is its object that is created in its function & only used to call a method then my method push into another view controller but it is not not pushing infect it calls its own loadView after executing "goToWatchList" method.

Comment: Check my edit above. I believe you are creating that new view controller (LoginViewController) and never adding it to the view hierarchy.